# GlusterFS as shared storage for ActiveMQ master/slave cluster

Tags: activemq-classic, cluster-computing, master-slave

I want to setup an ActiveMQ cluster. As I encountered problems with shared nothing approach, I'd like to do it using shared filesystem. However, the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html) warns about possible problems related to filesystem locks. As I'm not sure, I'd like to ask, if GlusterFS would be a good choice for shared filesystem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared-storage master-slave requires that the underlying file system supports network file locks. GlusterFS [seems to support network locks](http://gluster.org/community/documentation//index.php/GlusterFS_Technical_FAQ#How_is_locking_handled.3F) going by the documentation (it's not 100% clear). Ultimately the best way to find out is to set it up and check.

If it doesn't you still have the option of falling back to a shared JDBC-based store.