# ActiveMQ Shared File System Master Slave on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, activemq-classic, master-slave

We want to use an ActiveMQ [master/slave configuration based on a shared file system](http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html) on Amazon EC2 - that's the final goal. Operating system should be Ubuntu 12.04, but that shouldn't make too much difference.

*Why not a master/slave configuration based on RDS?* We've tried that and it's easy to set up (including multi-AZ). However, it is [relatively slow](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html) and the failover takes approximately three minutes - so we want to find something else.

*Which shared file system should we use?* We did some research and came to the following conclusion (which might be wrong, so please correct me):

- GlusterFS is [often suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415265/glusterfs-as-shared-storage-for-activemq-master-slave-cluster) and should be [supporting multi-AZs fine](http://sanketdangi.tumblr.com/post/5601762671/gluster-config-aws-multi-az).
- NFSv4 should be working (while NFSv3 is said to [corrupt the file system](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Feasibility-of-Shared-File-System-Master-Slave-using-NFSv4-td3536513.html)), but I didn't see too many references to it on EC2 (rather: [asked for NFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/347936/redundant-nfs-on-amazon-ec2), got the suggestion to use GlusterFS). Is there any particular reason for that?
- [Ubuntu's Ceph](http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/resources/white-papers/what%E2%80%99s-new-ubuntu-server-1204-lts) isn't stable yet.
- Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) sounds like overkill to me and the NameNode would again be a single point of failure.

*So GlusterFS it is?* We found hardly any success stories. Instead rather dissuasive entries in the bug tracker without any real explanation: ["I would not recommend using GlusterFS with master/slave shared file system with more than probably 15 enqueued/dequeued messages per second."](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4071) Does anyone know why or is anyone successfully using ActiveMQ on GlusterFS with a lot of messages?

*EBS or ephemeral storage?* Since GlusterFS should replicate all data, we could use the ephemeral storage or are there any advantages of using EBS (IMHO snapshots are not relevant for our scenario).

We'll probably try out GlusterFS, but according to Murphy's Law we'll run into problems at the worst possible moment. So we'd rather try to avoid that by (hopefully) getting a few more opinions on this. Thanks in advance!

PS: *Why didn't I post this on ServerFault?* It would be a better fit, but on SO there are 10 times more posts about this topic, so I stuck with the flock.

Comment: I have to make the same decision now, what you ended up using?

Comment: Currently Redis (at-most-once delivery is fine for our use case), but we're playing around with Disque. It's a bit early, but working quite well for us. Maybe my slides on the topic are helpful as well: https://speakerdeck.com/xeraa/a-tale-of-queues-from-activemq-over-hazelcast-to-disque :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea.... but with activemq 5.7 (or maybe already 5.6) you can have pluggable lockers (http://activemq.apache.org/pluggable-storage-lockers.html). So it might be an option to use the filesystem as storage and RDS as just a locking mechanism. Note I have never tried this before.